# Speed Controlling an AC motor

Tags: motor, motor-controller, ac-motor

Hello I have an [AC motor](https://xr-motor.en.made-in-china.com/product/ICJEBdkTYpWA/China-0-37kw-0-5HP-Yc-Series-Single-Phase-Capacitor-Start-Asynchronous-Motor-Yc80A-2-Yc80b-4.html) that i want to make a speed controller to, but before i start i want to make sure that it is possible with the type of motor i have. I do not want to waste the motor attempting to speed control it but then it is not possible.

How I plan to implement a speed control is to manipulate the AC waveform just like how you do it in dimming light bulbs. Using a non-zero Crossing SSR, zero crossing detection optocoupler, and a microcontroller.

Comment: That looks like an induction motor. Speed control by a 'light dimming' waveform change will be very non-linear. It may be OK in a feedback loop, it may possibly be OK with a fan load, but the speed will be very unstable into any varying load, and the torque will be very very low for low speeds. I would not recommend this attempt at speed control for this type of motor.

Comment: @Neil_UK "That looks like an induction motor." It is a (single-phase) induction motor. In this context "asynchronous" is a synonym for "induction" (meaning "not synchronous").

Comment: @Neil_UK I see thank you very much for the answer, may i ask what do industrial places that need big motors, and speed control uses?

Comment: Industry uses VFDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an asynchronous (also known as an induction) motor. This type of motor runs at a speed proportional to the frequency of the power supply. The proper way of controlling the speed of this type of motor is to vary the frequency of the supply using a device known as a variable frequency drive (VFD) or sometimes called an inverter.

A light dimmer can't vary the supply frequency, it just changes the amount of each half-cycle that is fed to the load. You can't use this principle to satisfactorily control your motor speed.

Note that the single-phase motor you linked to is specified for constant speed operation. VFDs work with 3-phase motors and need motors that are rated for use with VFDs/inverters. (The VFD output waveform can induce high-frequency currents in the motor rotor which return through the bearings of older motors, damaging them.)

So the best way of getting a variable speed motor is to get a 3-phase inverter rated motor and a VFD [rated to match the motor](https://www.google.com/search?q=0.5hp%20vfd%20single%20phase%20to%203%20or%20three%20phase). As you have a single phase motor now you presumably only have a single phase supply. You can get a VFD that takes in a single phase supply and provides a 3 phase output. If you do have a 3 phase supply available you can use a VFD with a 3 phase input.

Comment: Do VFD uses a closed loop system to regulate the speed? or its pretty much that at the a specific setting of this specific VFD will have a slightly different for different motors?

Comment: @DrakeJest Both

Comment: The frequency output of the VFD will set the basic motor speed but, as with a mains-connected motor, this will vary somewhat with load. You can add closed loop control if you need better speed regulation. Feel free to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=vfd+closed+loop+control) for details; there's plenty out there. Different VFD models offer different features so you can pick one to meet your requirements. (I'm afraid I'm not sufficiently familiar with them to recommend specific models though.)

Answer (score 2):

Not with this kind of motor. They count on a known phase shift (that’s the split-phase part) and frequency to run properly.

Chopping the AC as you propose adds harmonic distortion to that drive waveform. As you clip the waveform more, the motor will run rough, might slow down a bit, then stall.

A ‘universal’ motor on the other hand can be controlled in the way you propose.

Comment: Is a universal motor the best 220 AC capable type, for speed control? Is it the same type what industrial places that need speed control on motors?

Comment: They use ‘variable frequency drive’ and 3 phase motors. Basically, VFD converts the AC input to DC, then inverts it back to AC 3-phase with a variable frequency. The motor can follow along with that and will change its shaft speed to keep in sync

Comment: Universal motors today tend to be smaller - think power tools like drills and grinders. Their main drawback is that they have brushes like DC motors (and in fact can run on DC - that’s why they’re called ‘universal’.) They used to be used for bigger variable speed applications (like elevators, etc) but have since been supplanted by DC or VFD motors.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer. i have learned plenty :)